How can I fetch the data in React and PHP?
I write my React app to save the data in database by PHP but it gives me this error in console and don't save in database (I use xxamp): and the name of the columns in tbl table are isConfirmed and coursename.
POST http://localhost:3000/Components/saveCourses.php 404 (Not Found)
App.js:46 Fetch failed loading: POST "http://localhost:3000/Components/saveCourses.php".

enter image description here
This is my app.js:
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import CourseForm from './Components/CourseForm';
import CourseList from './Components/CourseList.js';

const App = () => {
  const [courses, setCourses] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchData();
  }, []);

  const fetchData = async () => {
    try {
      const response = await fetch('./Components/show.php');
      const data = await response.json();
      setCourses(data);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log('Error:', error);
    }
  };

  const addCourse = (courseName) => {
    setCourses([...courses, { name: courseName, isConfirmed: false }]);
  };

  const editCourse = (index) => {
    const newCourseName = prompt("Enter the new value:");
    if (newCourseName) {
      setCourses(courses.map((course, i) => i === index ? { ...course, name: newCourseName } : course));
    }
  };

  const deleteCourse = (index) => {
    setCourses(courses.filter((_, i) => i !== index));
  };

  const confirmCourse = (index) => {
    setCourses(courses.map((course, i) => i === index ? { ...course, isConfirmed: true } : course));
  };

  const saveCourses = async () => {
    const confirmSave = window.confirm("Are you sure you want to save the data?");
    if (confirmSave) {
      try {
        await fetch('./Components/saveCourses.php', {
          method: 'POST',
          headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
          body: JSON.stringify(courses)

        });
        alert("Courses saved successfully!");
      } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error:', error);
      }
    } else {
      alert("Save operation cancelled.");
    }
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <CourseForm addCourse={addCourse} />
      <CourseList courses={courses} editCourse={editCourse} deleteCourse={deleteCourse} confirmCourse={confirmCourse} />
      <button onClick={saveCourses}>Save DB</button>
      <button onClick={fetchData}>Show Data</button>
      <div id="dataContainer"></div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;


and this is the PHP file:
<?php


$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "courses";

$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
if (!$conn) {
    echo "Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error();
} 


$data = file_get_contents("php://input");
$ddd = json_decode($data, true);

$values = '';
foreach ($ddd as $row) {
    $values .= "('$row[name]', $row[isConfirmed]),";
}

$values = rtrim($values, ',');
$insertSql = "INSERT INTO tbl (coursename, isConfirmed) VALUES " . $values;

if (mysqli_query($conn, $insertSql)) {
    echo "Records saved successfully.";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $insertSql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($conn);
}



The PHP code itself likely isn't relevant if the server can't find the PHP file to handle the request.  Are you able to manually make a request to that PHP file, either in the browser or in a tool like Postman?

NO, I can't use postman just I can see the database if the data stored or not

If you can't use Postman specifically, at least use your browser.  Even if the code in the page is expected to fail from only an empty GET request, observing that specific failure can at least confirm that the page is found and is being executed.  Which would address the specific problem you're currently asking about.

If you're using Apache (under xampp) to serve the php then, unless you specifically changed the settings yourself, it won't be running on port 3000. Are you using a separate mechanism to serve the React app, by any chance?

P.s. this code is badly vulnerable to sql injection attacks, and to accidental sql syntax errors. Please urgently learn how to use prepared statements and parameters to build your queries safely and reliably. NEVER allow data from the client-side directly into a sql string like you're doing now. More info, and examples of the correct approach: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7537377/how-to-include-a-php-variable-inside-a-mysql-statement . It's 2024, nobody should be writing sql code like you've shown, or teaching anyone to do it like that. It's a disaster waiting to happen.

As you mentioned that you are using XAMPP then ensure that saveCourses.php is placed in directory accessible by your web server that is htDocs and you can update fetch call as http://localhost/saveCourses.php

Please ensure you xampp server running on the following url.
http://localhost:3000/Components/saveCourses.php
I think your xampp server use different port for running
e.g. http://localhost:8000/Components/saveCourses.php
